# Intersecting rectangles on a torus

Tags: c#, game, collision, monogame

**Description**

Imagine a space like the arcade game Asteroids where everything wraps around right to left and bottom to top - effectively coordinates on a flat torus. The diagram shows an example of two intersecting rectangles. The red rectangle at bottom right is wrapping around so that portions off screen are shown on the top and left, likewise with the blue.

[image: Picture of rectangles intersecting on a flat torus]

**Code**

The code takes in coordinates and width and height of two rectangles and the domain for x and y, and it returns whether they are intersecting given that they wrap around within the domain. I've included some test cases.

Asking for thoughts on improvements, optimisations, simplifications, bugs? etc...

```
// Preconditions: x1, w1, y1, h1, x2, w2, y2, h2 are between 0 and domain exclusive
bool IntersectsOnTorus(int x1, int w1, int y1, int h1, int x2, int w2, int y2, int h2, int domain)
{
    int r1 = x1 + w1;
    int r2 = x2 + w2;
    if (r1 < domain || r2 < domain)
    {
        r1 -= r1 >= domain ? domain : 0;
        r2 -= r2 >= domain ? domain : 0;
        if (x1 >= r2 && x2 >= r1 || x1 <= r1 && x2 <= r2 && (x1 >= r2 || x2 >= r1))
            return false;
    }
    int b1 = y1 + h1;
    int b2 = y2 + h2;
    if (b1 < domain || b2 < domain)
    {
        b1 -= b1 >= domain ? domain : 0;
        b2 -= b2 >= domain ? domain : 0;
        if (y1 >= b2 && y2 >= b1 || y1 <= b1 && y2 <= b2 && (y1 >= b2 || y2 >= b1))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Test(5, 10, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, false);
Test(5, 15, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, false);
Test(5, 17, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, true);
Test(5, 25, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, true);
Test(5, 28, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, true);
Test(5, 48, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, true);
Test(25, 28, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, true);
Test(30, 28, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, false);
Test(30, 45, 5, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 50, true);

void Test(int x1, int w1, int y1, int h1, int x2, int w2, int y2, int h2, int domain, bool expected)
{
    bool result1 = IntersectsOnTorus(x1, w1, y1, h1, x2, w2, y2, h2, domain);
    bool result2 = IntersectsOnTorus(x2, w2, y2, h2, x1, w1, y1, h1, domain);
    bool result3 = IntersectsOnTorus(y1, h1, x1, w1, y2, h2, x2, w2, domain);
    bool result4 = IntersectsOnTorus(y2, h2, x2, w2, y1, h1, x1, w1, domain);
    bool success = result1 == result2 && result2 == result3 && result3 == result4 && result1 == expected;
    Console.WriteLine($"""{result1}, {result2}, {result3}, {result4}, {(success ? "Success" : "Fail")}""");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool IntersectsOnTorus(int x1, int w1, int y1, int h1, int x2, int w2, int y2, int h2, int domain)
```

Choosing to phrase it as (x, w, y, h) instead of (x, y, w, h) seems
a bit odd, but OK, we can go with it.

---

```
    int r1 = x1 + w1;
    int r2 = x2 + w2;
    if (r1 < domain || r2 < domain)
    {
        r1 -= r1 >= domain ? domain : 0;
        r2 -= r2 >= domain ? domain : 0;
```

Didn't we want `r1 >= domain` rather than `<` ?

Is there some reason `%` modulo is not suitable here?
If so, it's worth documenting in a `// comment`.
If it's due to some timing measurement,
include a URL that describes details.

---

```
        if (x1 >= r2 && x2 >= r1 || x1 <= r1 && x2 <= r2 && (x1 >= r2 || x2 >= r1))
```

I imagine this is mostly correct.

It would be helpful to name some of those sub-expressions,
perhaps with identifiers like `x1_wrapped`.

Let's talk about some adjacent unit squares, with UL LR coords
of (0, 1) (1, 0) and (1, 1) (2, 0).
Now, are they "overlapping"?
I'm inclined to think the answer is "no".
I recommend using `lo <= x < hi` half-open intervals.
The current approach uses `lo <= x <= hi`.

---

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
The "bottom" calculations are essentially identical to the "right" calculations.
Consider rephrasing `(x, y)` as a single `location`.
Then we could Extract Helper and pass in `0` for
the "right" comparison and pass in `1` for the "bottom" comparison.

---

Wow, I really like the symmetries exposed by `Test()`, good job!

Comment: You're right about the (x,y,w,h) order I will edit. The (r1 < domain || r2 < domain) is right it means if both sides wrap then they must overlap, otherwise checks are needed. I tried to get away with not using % because division is slow and this will potentially be run many thousands of times a frame, those nanoseconds add up :/ ok not really. The next line does seem to work I was just wondering if there was some boolean simplification that could be done. For my purposes touching edges are not intersecting. Yes in the future I will need to check edge overlaps so that could be factored out.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the simplest possible intersection test--1D intervals on an infinite line--and build up the function we want.

What I've found in determining when things intersect is that the test for non-intersection (disjoint) is much simpler. The intervals are disjoint if the left edge of one is to the right of the right edge of the other, or if the right edge of one is to the left of the left edge of the other. This is simpler to express in code. For the 1D case:

```cs
// Returns whether the 1D intervals defined by left edges l1 and l2
// and widths w1 and w2 on an infinite line are non-intersecting.
// Touching at edges or corners do not count as intersecting.
bool AreDisjoint1d(int l1, int w1, int l2, int w2)
{
    int r1 = l1 + w1;
    int r2 = l2 + w2;
    return l1 >= r2 || r1 <= l2;
}

bool AreIntersecting1d(int l1, int w1, int l2, int w2)
{
    return ! AreDisjoint1d(l1, w1, l2, w2);
}
```

We can use these 1D functions to define the 2D intersection by the following fact: rectangles intersect if both their X intervals and Y intervals intersect. So,

```cs
bool AreIntersecting2d(int x1, int w1, int y1, int h1, int x2, int w2, int y2, int h2)
{
    return AreIntersecting1d(x1, w1, x2, w2) && AreIntersecting1d(y1, h1, y2, h2);
}
```

Now we come to the problem of doing this on a torus. Changing your mental image of the problem can help here. Instead of imagining shapes split over the border of the domain, imagine that the domain is replicated infinitely on a 2D grid. This way, the shapes simply move into the next identical grid instead of warping to the other side of one grid. All of these grids are identical, so they all contain the same shapes, like this:
[image: Replicated game domain extended in two dimensions.]

If any of the copies of one shape intersect any copy of the other shape, then they intersect. Now, we can write our intersection on a torus function:

```cs
bool IntersectsOnTorus(int x1, int w1, int y1, int h1, int x2, int w2, int y2, int h2, int domain)
{
    return AreIntersecting2d(x1, w1, y1, h1, x2, w2, y2, h2)                    // No wrapping
        || AreIntersecting2d(x1 + domain, w1, y1, h1, x2, w2, y2, h2)           // Shape 2 wraps left edge
        || AreIntersecting2d(x1, w1, y1 + domain, h1, x2, w2, y2, h2)           // Shape 2 wraps bottom edge
        || AreIntersecting2d(x1 + domain, w1, y1 + domain, h1, x2, w2, y2, h2)  // Shape 2 wraps bottom-left corner
        || AreIntersecting2d(x1, w1, y1, h1, x2 + domain, w2, y2, h2)           // Shape 1 wraps left edge
        || AreIntersecting2d(x1, w1, y1, h1, x2, w2, y2 + domain, h2)           // Shape 1 wraps bottom edge
        || AreIntersecting2d(x1, w1, y1, h1, x2 + domain, w2, y2 + domain, h2); // Shape 1 wraps bottom-left corner
}
```

There are other ways to write this. For the Shape 1 wrapping cases, you could also subtract the domain from the Shape 1 coordinates. I wrote it this way to keep all coordinates positive, in case that matters later, like if `int`s are replaced with `unsigned int`s in the future.

The best part of writing the code this way is that the tricky math is confined to one function, and that function only has to consider the simplest case. Every other function consists of combinations of calls to other functions that are much easier to read and check for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

As a further answer I've found another method that maybe more efficient. It works by taking the centres of the rectangles and calculating the distance between them modulo the domain. If the centres are close enough, less than (w1 + w2) / 2, they are overlapping.

Again the modulo operator can be avoided in favour of comparisons because of the preconditions - yes, there is a measurable difference in benchmarks.

This version does however use doubles instead of ints, the int version breaks here.

```
// Preconditions: x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2 are between 0 and domain exclusive
bool IntersectsOnTorus(double x1, double y1, double w1, double h1, double x2, double y2, double w2, double h2, double domain)
{
    // Difference between the centres modulo domain
    double dx = (dx = x1 + w1 / 2 - x2 - w2 / 2) < 0
        ? dx + domain : dx >= domain ? dx - domain : dx;

    // Separation of centres when touching
    double sx = (w1 + w2) / 2;

    // Similar for y
    double dy = (dy = y1 + h1 / 2 - y2 - h2 / 2) < 0
        ? dy + domain : dy >= domain ? dy - domain : dy;
    double sy = (h1 + h2) / 2;

    // Return true if the absolute* difference between centres
    // is less than touching distance
    return (dx < sx || dx > domain - sx) && (dy < sy || dy > domain - sy);
}
```

- I'm using the span between 0 and domain as a *signed* number. Eg. in MOD 10 you'd have 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1. In this way you can avoid "date line" issues like there was in Defender arcade.

Orginal question [Intersecting rectangles on a torus](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/282772/244707).

Comment: While it is definitely okay to answer your own question if you want a new review of the modified code it is better if you post a follow up question with a link back to this question.

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Compute `dx` with a function or (gasp!) a cpp macro, then same for `dy`. (This codebase does not use `[0]` for X, `[1]` for Y, and that is perfectly fine, but _one_ way to parameterize a helper would be by passing in a `0` / `1` subscript.) The double ternary operator is _too long_. Add (redundant) parentheses to help human readers, and maybe put each on its own line.

Comment: @J_H I wish C# had macros, it does however have attributes for inlining small methods which is what I use. I also have functions called WrapToWidth and WrapToHeight that I use all over my own code. I forgot to include them here sorry. Comments taken onboard.